# Trying to send XMPP IQ stanza with Strophe

Tags: javascript, xml, xmpp, strophe

I'm trying to send an IQ stanza to request the user's roster using the strophe library. Strophe provides a function for this, called [sendIQ](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs/blob/afa7cfb/src/core.js#L2153-L2203).

I tried to send the IQ stanza like this:

```
let iq_str = "<iq type='get' id='roster1'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/></iq>";
let parser = new DOMParser();
let iq = parser.parseFromString(iq_str, "text/xml");
XMPP.conn.sendIQ(iq, onRoster);
```

However, strophe's sendIQ function crashes in the `var id = elem.getAttribute('id');` line with a `TypeError: e.getAttribute is not a function` error, because (if I understand correctly), `iq` is not a XML element object, but a XML document object.

After some searching, I was able to avoid the crash by doing this instead:

```
let iq_str = "<iq type='get' id='roster1'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/></iq>";
let parser = new DOMParser();
let iq = parser.parseFromString(iq_str, "text/xml").getElementsByTagName("iq")[0];
XMPP.conn.sendIQ(iq, onRoster);
```

But this way I'm obviously not receiving any reply since I'm not specifying the query in the passed `iq` variable.

I have the feeling that I must be missing something very trivial but I've been stuck for a while. All the example I've found use jQuery, but I believe there has to be a solution without using it.

Comment: My bad, `getElementsByTagName` does return the child elements so the IQ was correct. The problem was an error in the callback `onRoster` that I failed to notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to use Strophe's own [Strophe.Builder](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.10/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Builder.Strophe.Builder) constructor to create XML stanzas NOT the browser's DOMParser API.

Instead of invoking Strophe.Builder directly, you can do this by using the utility functions [Strophe.$msg](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.10/files/strophe-js.html#$msg) (for "message" stanzas), [Strophe.$pres](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.10/files/strophe-js.html#$pres) (for "presence" stanzas) and [Strophe.$iq](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.10/files/strophe-js.html#$iq) (for "IQ" stanzas).

Child elements are added via the [c](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.10/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Builder.c) method and text via the [t](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.10/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Builder.t) method.

For example:

```
$msg({'to': 'someond@example.org'}).c('body').t('Hello world!);
```

These functions and methods return the generated Strophe.Builder object. So if you have used `c` to add a child, it will return that child. If you want to add another child, to the parent, you use [up](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.10/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Builder.up) to move the context back up to the parent.

For example:

```
$msg({'to': 'someond@example.org'}).c('child1').up().c('child2');
```

There's also a more general, lower-level [$build](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.10/files/strophe-js.html#$build) function which is called by $msg, $pres and $iq and which you can use to generate other XML stanzas, but it's very rarely needed.

So to create and send your specific IQ stanza, you'd do something like this:

```
let iq = $iq({'type':'get', 'id':'roster1'}).c('query', {'xmlns':'jabber:iq:roster'});
XMPP.conn.sendIQ(iq, onRoster);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. I had actually tried that already though (it was the first example I found), but kept getting a _$iq is not defined_ error. I eventually thought that the reason it failed was because it was actually jQuery, but now I see I was wrong. I keep getting the same error though.

Comment: Nevermind, I added $iq to the strophe import and it worked.